# Cause of Spoiled idli?

Tags: dough, indian-cuisine, batter

I have prepared idli which was spoiled after steaming.
I followed the following process:

1. Soaked idli rava (coarsely ground rice) along with whole black gram(without skin).
2. Grinded with mixie to become batter; Left overnight to ferment.

Idli came out like this when steamed:

[image]

What could be the reason?

Comment: What colour was the batter before steaming?

Comment: @mbjb Dull white. This is the first time I have seen something like this. I have prepared idli many times and everytime it was good as it should be.  What shocked me here is the color and it's structure.

Comment: **1** What is the ratio of rice to dal? **2** Did you add Fenugreek seeds? **3** Did you add salt before fermentation? **4** What was the smell like after fermentation?

Comment: @AJN:      1. 2:1.    2.Yes.   3.Yes.   4. Normal smell as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Fermentation is a crucial step in idli-making as it helps the batter rise and develop a fluffy texture. It's possible that the batter didn't ferment properly or for long enough. Factors such as temperature and humidity can affect the fermentation process. Ideally, the batter should be left to ferment in a warm place for at least 8-12 hours, or until it has increased in volume and developed a slightly sour smell.
The ratio of idli rava (coarsely ground rice) to black gram (urad dal) could also impact the outcome. The typical ratio for idli batter is 4:1 (four parts rice to one part dal).

Although the image you shared clearly represents that the batter was not properly fermented. The same thing happened to me and I came to
conclusion that my proportion was not right which led to non-fermentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information.